# testing-library/react - why toHaveFocus return the wrong focused element?

Tags: reactjs, material-ui, react-testing-library

I develop `select` component using `Material-UI select`.

Using `testing-library/react` to test the component.

I have `search input` in the select menu. when open it should be focused.

On the browser my solution is working fine, but in the test it fails.

the fail is that the first item is focused, not the search input as expected.

The first item contain the search input, but i checked with chrome activeElement. in the browser the focused element on open is the `input` not it's container. also, the typing cursor is shows in the input.

I tried using:

1. `waitFor` - so the test will wait until the menu is open. it didn't work.
2. `findBy` - same as above but i wait here for the element to be shown.
3. I see in the test log that it does find the right element, it is just not focused.

this is the component related code:

```
const searchRef = useRef<HTMLInputElement>();
  useEffect(() => {
    if (searchRef.current && (isOpen || search)) {
      searchRef.current?.focus();
    }
  }, [search, isOpen, searchRef.current]);



<MUISelect> 
<MUIMenuItem
      value=""
      onClickCapture={stopImmediatePropagation}
      onKeyDown={(event: React.KeyboardEvent<HTMLLIElement>) => {
        event.stopPropagation();
      }}
      classes={searchContainerClasses}
      key="search"
      disableRipple
    >
      <Input
        inputRef={searchRef}
        endAdornment={<SearchIcon />}
        classes={searchClasses}
        placeholder={searchPlaceholder}
        onChange={onSearch}
        value={search}
        autoFocus
      />
    </MUIMenuItem>
// menu items
</MUISelect>
```

the test:

```
const props = {
  placeholder: 'Select...',
  options: [
    { text: 'Itay Bank', value: 'itay bank' },
    { text: 'Einat Capital', value: 'einat capital' },
    { text: 'Shay Street', value: 'shay street' },
  ],
  prefix: 'Counterparty',
  value: '',
  onChange: (value: any) => console.log(value),
};

it('should focus search input, when searchable and opend', () => {
    const searchPlaceholder = 'search';
    const { getByText, getByPlaceholderText } = render(
      <Filter {...props} searchable searchPlaceholder={searchPlaceholder} />
    );

    fireEvent.click(getByText(props.placeholder));

    expect(getByPlaceholderText(searchPlaceholder)).toHaveFocus();
  });
```

the error:

[image: Fail test]

**Edit 1**

Not sure why, but in codesandbox the input ref is null, so i can't show the problem yet... if you can see the issue let me know ill fix it.
codesandbox: https://codesandbox.io/s/filter-wf5z2?file=/src/Filter.js

Comment: So this didn't work? 

`await waitFor() =>  expect(getByPlaceholderText(searchPlaceholder)).toHaveFocus();`

Comment: @ReturnOfTheMac nope

Comment: Can you put a codesandbox together so we can help you better?

Comment: @ReturnOfTheMac maybe later

Comment: Here's the link in case you need it: https://codesandbox.io/s/fziwm

Comment: @ReturnOfTheMac i maid something it's in the post edit. but it doesn't show the issue yet, because i couldnt manage it to work in the browser first (inputRef.current is null in useEffect for some reason). if you can take a look it would be really helpful.